# Is the loop in this python code breaking because of duplicate values in the column?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcpy

This code is meant take a shapefile in the current mxd, loop through all of the values in a collumn of said shapefile. For each value it will create a definition query, zoom to features then save a copy of the mxd.  When I run the code it completes, but only generates one mxd when I'm expecting about 25.

Is the loop breaking due to duplicate values in the Field_1 collumn? If so how can I work around, if not what is breaking the loop after one single iteration?

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env
#Overwrite features
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
shape = r"C:\NewProjects\shapes\Meters.shp"
output = r"C:\NewProjects\shapes"
layer = r"C:\NewProjects\shapes\newlyr"
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\NewProjects\shapes\Try.mxd")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
inset = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
lyr1 = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "Meters", df)[0]  # pick the layer you want to "extract" data from
#For each work order:
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(lyr1, "", "", "FIELD_1", "FIELD_1 A")
for row in rows:
    name = str(row.getValue('FIELD_1'))
    sqlExp = """"FIELD_1" ='"""  + str(row.getValue('FIELD_1'))+"""'"""    # Create a clause to select only the current record
    lyr1.definitionQuery = sqlExp
    df.extent = lyr1.getSelectedExtent(True)
newMxd = "Figure1_" + name
mxd.saveACopy(r"C:\NewProjects\shapes\\" + newMxd + ".mxd")
print "Saving ", newMxd + ".mxd"
print "All done."
del mxd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try including your code to name and save the mxd within your for loop

Comment: Somehow that completely slipped me. This worked perfectly.  A little more tinkering and I've just saved myself a couple days of work over the next few weeks.

Thank you!